# next/navigation Error 404 dynamic routes only in production NEXT13

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Hello everybody i have a problem using NEXT's dynamic routing (Next 13)
I have this structurr

```
- user/
-- [id]/
--- page.js
```

and this is working on dev mode but not in prod.

What im trying?

Im make a "page.js" inside user folder with this config on it

```
export const dynamic = 'auto'
export const dynamicParams = true
export const revalidate = false
export const fetchCache = 'auto'
export const runtime = 'nodejs'
export const preferredRegion = 'auto'
export const maxDuration = 5
 
export default function MyComponent() {}
```

I not using "generateStaticParams" because the param is generated randomly on backend and sended to user email.

there are any way to solve this? Thanks for the answers

Comment: This will be helpful in your case [Next.js Docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/deploying/static-exports#client-components)

Answer (score 0):

I solved this!

change my next.config from

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  images: {
    unoptimized: true,
  },
  ouput: "export",
  reactStrictMode: true,
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

to

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  images: {
    unoptimized: true,
  },
  reactStrictMode: true,
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

the "export" was generating a static ouput